# flash air or any other wifi card for web app?

Tags: web-applications, wifi, sd-card, flashair

according to flash air developer if viewing/downloading /uploading content from a web browser or smart phone web browser I have to copy some files to the card . 
Can I get access to the card without copying any file to the card? The reason I am asking is I am developing a WEB APP ( not a native android or iOS app) that need to connect and have access to the card but if  I succeed in this app I can not tell people to buy the card and make them to copy some files to the card. I need the app directly have access to the card a from within the web app make them change password and setting for the card
Is this possible with this card or any other wi-fi card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the app i just did can meet your request. but it is not the web based. You will have to make your own web app/script then.

if you are interested, i can share the code to you. Basically, the http request from android app is the same with web app.

check it out

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chiarly.mylocalcloud&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

The files you normally copy to the card are to configure it as a unique card.

Otherwise the cards all arrive with same defaults.

While the cards have different MACs the default password [12345678] and URL [http://flashair/] will be the same for all the cards.  This means you can read any new card without writing any files to the card.

However, you need to know/change the MasterCode to write to the card and as far as I can tell that is different from card to card.

So reading is okay, writing requires the user at-least read the config file to get the MasterCode and enter it into your app.  I have not tried it, but it may be possible to read the config from your app and get the MasterCode that way.